# Cannot run Amazon Q / CodeWhisperer on VS Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, amazon-codewhisperer

I tried to use Amazon Q in VS Code but somehow it keeps loading forever. Does anyone know what could be the issue? I was able to use it at onetime but somehow it is not responding. I tried reload vs code or re-enable Amazon Q or reinstall Amazon Q. None of these work.

[image]

For example, I tried to reconnect codewhisperer, and receive below message:
[image]

If I tried to add a new connection, then I receive below message:
[image]